# Does external column data refresh change list items' modified and modified by?

Tags: external-data

I have SharePoint list having External Data column. Now I want to refresh that column data.

I can do it through UI using refresh button at top on the column. But I am not sure whether it will change list item modified and modified by as I tried to find it on google but did not get my answer.

I just want to make sure If I refresh data it should not change modified and modified by.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At least the version isn't updated in these scenarios. I have a previous answer regarding that in [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149897/version-history-does-not-update-when-lookup-changes-how-to-fix/149900#149900).

Comment: I agree but as I am aware external column's value does not get change automatically if you change into source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I found my answer. **It updates modified and modified by**. I tried by creating sample list and tested with that list before doing into actual list.

Comment: Hey man. I have answer my own question. Whats wrong in it?

Comment: If I not answer then this post will be unanswered forever. Is it fine? and why down vote?